# Retraining azure ml with all data in a blob container via c#

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I have a use case. In this each month I will receive a csv which contain history data for predicting an value. 
Currently i upload around 2 year of data to a blob container.
In ml training experiment i am importing all CSV in this container. When I convert my training to retraining i could see a web service input has been added parallel to my import.

Doubts
1)if I receive a csv next month and I give this CSV as web service input, in my ilearner output depends only on current data. Means whatever training i had done so far will be lost. Is that how it's working or not.

2) if I go and delete my web service input from my training exp will it start from importing all data from my blob container.

3)how to handle same situation if input is an azure table storage. There i need my training exp to import all data from table storage for each retraining.

Any help will be appreciated.